# It's possible to filter SP Modern Page Content with URL params?

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, content, pnp-search-webparts

The challenge here is to get filters applied to certain content (on SPO-OOTB or PnP Modern Search v4 webparts) via URL params.

Query String URL Tricks for SharePoint and Microsoft 365
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/query-string-url-tricks-sharepoint-m365

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? What are you trying to achieve URL parameters specifically? SharePoint doesn't use them everywhere but does sometimes with search for example.

Comment: I want to filter some webparts content via URL params. More specifically, you have a Highlighted content webpart and I want to define a custom query which will rely on a URL param passed on.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I don't believe the highlighted content web part accepts URL parameters. I've certainly never seen URL parameters used with it by Microsoft or anyone else. As for the PnP Modern Search web part, it might accept URL parameters but if it doesn't it's open source so you could fork the project and build that functionality on to it.

Comment: thank you for your input @CallumCrowley